# facebook session check on login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have put the following code in my head to check the session:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.session) {
                alert('I am logged in');
              } else {
                alert('I am logged out');
              }
            });
    </script>
```

however, it does not get executed on page load, why is this?

Comment: Have you included FB's javascript library? You'd need that to get the FB object. Check your javascript error console (shift-ctrl-J in firefox, for instance) to check for error messages.

Comment: it's this one right?
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

Comment: I'd suggest reading Facebook's API docs. Sounds like you're engaging in some cargo cult programming. If you're blindly including code in your page with no idea of how it works, or how to make it work, then you should seriously think about stepping back and learning why.

Comment: nevermind, I fixed it.. turns out I need to call init and add the div root inside the body..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have:

```
FB.init({
    appId  : APP_ID, // Your FB app ID from www.facebook.com/developers/
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

before any other FB reference in your scripts (using window.onload or similar) and

```
<DIV id="fb-root"></div>
```

in the `<body>` section.